# What is the probability of having 10 or more crashes in the first 1000 rides?

Tags: probability, statistics, binomial-distribution

You have recently invested in an electric skateboard. You always wear a helmet and padding to protect yourself (of course), but are worried that at some point you'll take a tumble and get scratched up. After assessing your skating ability, you estimate your probability of a crash on any single ride to be $0.005$.

I got this question while studying geometric and binomial distribution.

My current idea is

$1 - (P(x=0) + P(x=1) + P(x=2) + \ldots + P(x=9))$

where $x$ is the number of crashes, and get each probability by binomial distribution's formula.

I came up with this equation as I thought having $10$ or more crashes means same as not having $9$ or less crashes.
Is my approach correct? Also, if it's correct, is there any way to simplify the calculation?

Comment: I think your approach is correct. I think one way to "simplify" the calculation is by using the Poisson approximation. If $X =$ number of crashes then $X$ is approximately Poisson with $\lambda = 1000(.005)$ and then you can do $P(X \ge 10) = 1-P(X=0) -P(X=1) \cdots$